# Android Gmail client table spacing

Tags: android, html, gmail, html-email, email-client

Is this an Android gmail client bug? I created a responsive mailer and only android gmail client renders the table wrongly.  All the rest are ok.  The code can be seen at this link - [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=atqr5V47) or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eSIlIYax/1/)

P.S. I forgot the closing html tag. On my mailer all are properly nested and closed.

Comment: Gmail doesn't support all the HTML tags.

Comment: I'm mostly using tables. And this is just a simple layout. My previous codes worked well but at this time it's not working well

Comment: Well, its a Gmail issue. Tags like `src` and `href` are also not rendering properly.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail can render emails quite well if you program them properly. Your HTML look fairly well formed. So I don't see that you should have much trouble getting this to render correctly.

A couple notes:

1. Android Gmail app does not have full support of `@media` queries. If your email isn't 'responding' properly on Android Gmail that is the reason.
2. In order to make sure you don't get spacing issues around images your images should always have `style="display:block"`. And if your image is sitting in a table cell make sure you add `style=font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;"` on the table cell. This will ensure that email clients don't render and extra spacing above and below images (I usually see this in Outlook, but I've come across it in Gmail too).

Comment: The problem with adding font-size:1px is the alt text will be too small when images are hidden at first.  Though I already tried adding the font-size and line-height as well.  I wonder if this is really a GMAIL app problem or something wrong with the code.

Comment: I've never had a problem with the gap. Providing you have `margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display:block;` in your image CSS and it sits alone in a `<td>`, you don't need all the font and line height stuff.

Comment: Even with `margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display:block;` I've noticed problems. And if we want to be picky: `font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;` is less code than all the margin stuff on all images. :P This technique usually works for me. If you're concerned with how your alt tags will look if images don't show, you can apply the css styling on the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

^ You should avoid setting font-size to less than 5px because SpamAssassin sees that style as an identifier of spammy content. Gmail mobile's problem is that it has a default line-height of 16px on table cells. Set the line-height lower (but not <5px) on the `<td>` of whatever content is breaking the layout.